# Is there any Ubuntu PDF reader which can select (snapshot) , save, and export pages?

Tags: pdf

I installed Foxit in Ubuntu 14.04 but it doesn't seem to have the 'snapshot' feature of the Windows version, ability to save and export a page to..say..Libroffice to save as a word page doc. Does such a PDF program exist for Ubuntu? Or have I installed Foxit wrong?

Comment: Foxit for Linux does not have the full feature set that the Windows version does, although I use it myself and find it to be pretty handy.  You can use PDF-Shuffler to extract a single page, or print the single page to a cups-pdf printer.  Libre-office can read pdf as images, I believe.

Comment: Very useful reply. But I don't see any way to "thumbs up" your answer.

Comment: @Charles Green  -  My PDF opens in PDF Shuffler, but the images are very blurred.

Comment: Why is there no way for me to vote up your answer @Charles Green?

Answer (score 1):

Foxit for Linux does not have the full feature set that the Windows version does, although I use it myself and find it to be pretty handy. You can use PDF-Shuffler to extract a single page, or print the single page to a cups-pdf printer. Libre-office can read pdf as images, I believe.